# how to customize jquery-steps?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-steps

I'm using this jquery plugin;

https://github.com/rstaib/jquery-steps

and I want to create my own next and previous button inside my container or another place .

plugin has documentation page https://github.com/rstaib/jquery-steps/wiki but I couldn't find way how to do it ?

edit: I don't want to change name of button.I want to create my own next and previous button in my container thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I did this so I created this new function:

```
function _goToStep(wizard, options, state, index)
{
    return paginationClick(wizard, options, state, index);
}
```

And the call that is not implemented, put this:

```
$.fn.steps.setStep = function (step)
{

    var options = getOptions(this),
        state = getState(this);

    return _goToStep(this, options, state, step);

};
```

Just taking advantage of what already existed plugin.

Use:

```
wizard.steps("setStep", 1);
```

You may look for http://www.jquery-steps.com/Examples on "Advanced Form Example". it may help you.

Comment: when I used this function it just chancing name of button which is existing.

Comment: I have a form and it has got buttons end of bottom but I want to add inside of form not end bottom of bottom

Comment: yes you can dynamically call steps using wizard.steps("setStep", 1)
it will move you to 1st step

Comment: I added but what do I have to add html ? <a href="#setStep"> or ?

Comment: it depend upon your logic. you may use <a href="setSteps(1)">go on step 1</a>

and function setSteps(step){ wizard.steps("setStep", step); }

kind of this. all depend upon your usage. there are may ways to bnd events.

Comment: no didn't work again Iit gives me a error..wizard is not defined..''m working with this plugin http://www.jquery-steps.com/ may be can be updated with all configuration